# Copy paste values triggered by worksheet change event is not working

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am using worksheet change event to trigger copy paste values. Worksheet change code is in the sheet2

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Set Target = Range("AB2")
If Target.Value = "OK" Then
    Call myTR1
End If
```

**Please note AB2 cell takes it's value from another sheet**

Copy paste code is in a Module

```
Sub myTR1()
Sheets("BA1").Range("AR6:AS8").Value = Sheets("BA1").Range("AL17:AM19").Value
End Sub
```

When target range changes to "OK", my copy paste macro is not triggering. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `worksheet_change` has small `w` and small `c` so I am guessing the code is in a module and not the relevant worksheet

Comment: Try to use other name for variable than `Target`, for example `TargetCell`. Isn't it 'special' word in VBA?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, worksheet change code is in the relevant sheet. Copy paste values code is in a module.

Comment: So if you right-click on the sheet tab, View Code, that code appears in the editor?

Comment: @Teamothy unfortunately still no result after changing variable name from Target to TargetCell

Comment: There are two ways then. Either rename your target like @Teamothy mentioned or use Intersect as shown in my answer below.

Comment: @SJR yes, worksheet change event code appears. Copy and paste values code is in one of the Modules.

Comment: `Please note AB2 cell takes it's value from another sheet` OH DAMN!!!! I just noticed... In this case `Worksheet_Change` will not work

Comment: You may want to rethink this from `Worksheet_Calculate()` point of view

Answer (score 0):

Using your eaxct code worked, although you didnt have end sub in your example?

EDIT:
Bear in mind the 'OK' is case sensitive so it will have to be in uppercase to fire, if you want it to fire either on lower or upper you can use the second code.

```
    Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Set Target = Range("AB2")
    If Target.Value = "OK" Then
        Call myTR1
    End If
    End Sub
```

---

```
    Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Set Target = Range("AB2")
    If Target.Value = "OK" Or Target.Value = "ok" Then
        Call myTR1
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am tracking mutiple cells AB2, AB3...AB200 using End Ifs. I have End Sub at the end. My changed value "OK" is upper case, however cells AB2 - AB200 are linked to other worksheets. Perhaps this is why change event is not triggering the macro, strictly speaking value hasn't changed, it's just the formula that was updated? Any workaround this? Thanks.

Comment: Im not too sure because as a test ive just set the value to AB2 as "=AB5"

I then change the value of AB5 to 'OK' which in turn updates the AB2 cell, and then it fires the Worksheet change event

Comment: Thanks for checking. It works for me in other columns, not for AB. I have just changed the tracker column to AC and worksheet change event is now firing macro. I am not sure why AB column didn’t work in first instance.